# Issues with random.choice()

Tags: python

So I am working on a little text based Python game to work on learning the language, and in one of the scenarios, I am trying to do a random draw.

```
import random
chance = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = random.choice(chance)

if result == 1 or 2:
    print("Better luck next time!)

elif result == 3 or 4 or 5:
    print("Congrats! You made it through")
```

And for some reason whenever I run the code, I always get the the if result, and never the elif. I know this could be random, but I figured I would check here just to be sure. Also, I do have an else statement I just didn't feel it was relevant for me to have to type it.

Comment: Why not just `if result > 2`?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks